# Reading strings from within a file to a array

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, getline

I have a text file with multiple rows and columns in the following manner.

```
 234 567 890 4523
 12  34  
 78  23  432
```

I'd like to read them into an array such that `a[0][0] = 234`, while `a[1][0] = 12` and so on. I can get them all into a single dimensional using `input >> a[i]` , but I'd like it in a two-dimensional array. I tried using `getline()` but haven't had any success so far.

Comment: <del>you can use `>>` in the same for a two-dimensional array as for a one-dimensional array. just like you can drive a green car in the same way as a red car. the array dimensionality (car color) is irrelevant.</del> well the data example changed so what i wrote, while true, doesn't apply... the question appears to really be about how to detect the array size from the data

Comment: space delimited with the new row being started when a newline is reached. Right? Is that what you are trying?

Comment: In a true C++ multidimensional array, all rows have the same number of columns; but in your example, the different lines have different numbers of fields. Maybe you want to use a *jagged array* (also called a *ragged array* or an *array of arrays*) instead? Or perhaps a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. The number of columns isn't the same for every row.

Comment: @Syed: . . . which means that you don't actually want a multidimensional array. Please decide what you want instead.

Comment: Like you said, it is not a true multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `std::vector` of `std::vector`.

for each line, read in each number and use `push_back` to copy it to the end of the relevant vector (array).

you can read from a string, representing the line of input, by using a `std::istringstream`.

you can read in one line of input into a `std::string`, as you noted, by using `std::getline`.

---

in pseudo-code it goes like

```
void foo()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > numbers;
    std::string line;
    while( getline( cin, line ) )
    {
        std::istringstream stream( line );
        numbers.push_back( std::vector<int>() );
        std::vector<int>& v = numbers.back();
        int number;
        while( stream >> number )
        {
            v.push_back( number );
        }
    }
}
```

disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands, and all error checking etc. omitted.